# sql server 2008 r2: case statement in where clause for current fiscal year

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, case

I'm trying to write code where I want to only see requests from the current fiscal year. Our fiscal year starts July 1st and ends June 30th

But when I write the following code

```
SELECT
    group_name
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'HOLD'THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS HOLD    
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'CL'THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CL
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'OP'THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS OP
FROM dbo.View_Request 
WHERE CASE WHEN datepart(mm, GetDate()) > 6 THEN /*It is past June in this year*/
            datepart(mm,dateadd(second,open_date,'19700101')) >= 7
            AND datepart(yy,dateadd(second,open_date,'19700101')) = datepart(yy, GetDate())
        ELSE /*It is June 30th or earlier in the year*/
            CASE WHEN datepart(mm,dateadd(second,open_date,'19700101')) <= 6 THEN
                datepart(yy,dateadd(second,open_date,'19700101')) = datepart(yy, GetDate())
            ELSE
                datepart(yy,dateadd(second,open_date,'19700101')) = datepart(yy, GetDate())-1
            END
        END
GROUP BY group_name
```

I get the vague error message:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
>   Incorrect syntax near '>'.

How do I fix this code to only examine entries from the current fiscal year

Answer (score 2):

Your first case is a bit funny:

```
CASE WHEN datepart(mm, GetDate()) > 6 THEN /*It is past June in this year*/
        datepart(mm,dateadd(second,open_date,'19700101')) >= 7  
        AND datepart(yy,dateadd(second,open_date,'19700101')) = datepart(yy, GetDate())
```

See that second and third line?? What are they??

Your CASE statement should always be:

```
CASE WHEN (condition) THEN (return value)
     WHEN (condition 2) THEN (return value 2)
     ...
     ELSE (return value x)
END
```

Those two lines really don't fit in there - after the `WHEN` keyword, you should have just a simple expression that returns a single value - not two lines of code.....

Comment: I figured it out: WHERE (
  (datepart(yy, dateadd(second,open_date,'19700101')) = datepart(yy, GetDate()) AND datepart(mm, dateadd(second,open_date,'19700101')) > 6 AND datepart(mm, GetDate()) > 6)
  OR
  (datepart(yy, dateadd(second,open_date,'19700101')) = datepart(yy, GetDate()) AND datepart(mm, dateadd(second,open_date,'19700101'))<= 6 AND datepart(mm, GetDate())<= 6)
  OR
  (datepart(yy, dateadd(second,open_date,'19700101')) = datepart(yy, GetDate()-1) AND datepart(mm, dateadd(second,open_date,'19700101'))> 6 AND datepart(mm, GetDate())<= 6)
 )

Comment: @jsmith: could you please update your question with the solution - here in comments, it's **really hard** to read.....